# How can I dynamically set UIView constraints?

Tags: ios, constraints, sdwebimage

I have a custome UITableViewCell. It contains labels and UIImageViews from the top to bottom. I added constraints to labels and UIImageViews. So I can use systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: UILayoutFittingCompressedSize to caculate the cell height that fit the content. But the image in the UIImageView is loaded from online using SDWebImage. At first I can set some constraints to the UIImageView. When the image is loaded, I should change the UIImageView's constraint to meet its size. But sometimes an error occurs. Sometimes it's ok:

> *** Assertion failure in -[NSLayoutConstraint _setSymbolicConstant:constant:], /SourceCache/Foundation_Sim/Foundation-1142.14/Layout.subproj/NSLayoutConstraint.m:585
>   2015-04-01 19:57:44.537 HiPDA[3760:63583]
>
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Constant is not finite!  That's illegal.  constant:nan'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001113cfa75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111068bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001113cf8da +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
>       3   Foundation                          0x000000010ef0cb6f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
>       4   Foundation                          0x000000010ee87c7d -[NSLayoutConstraint _setSymbolicConstant:constant:] + 149

The code is:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
__weak typeof(UIImageView *) weakImgView=imgView;
[imgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dic objectForKey:THREADLISTDETAILIMAGE]] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

    CGFloat width=image.size.width>maxWidth?maxWidth:image.size.width;
    NSLayoutConstraint *imgW1=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:weakImgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.0 constant:width];
    [weakSelf.contentView addConstraint:imgW1];
    NSLayoutConstraint *imgH1=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:weakImgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.0 constant:width*image.size.height/image.size.width];
    [weakSelf.contentView addConstraint:imgH1];

    [weakSelf needsUpdateConstraints];
    [weakSelf layoutIfNeeded];
    [weakSelf layoutSubviews];
}];
```

And if the image is downloaded completely, the tableview doesn't refresh. I can see the image came out of the cell size. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take Outlet NSLayoutConstraint for the imageView and programmatically you can change the value like

self.imgViewHeightConstraint.constant = 300 (some value)

Comment: and when the image is loaded ,how to call the tableview to refresh. the first picture shows when image loaded :http://imgsrc.baidu.com/forum/w%3D580/sign=a7990bbd69224f4a5799731b39f69044/70fea018367adab45f8f66d88fd4b31c8601e431.jpg  the second refresh manually :http://imgsrc.baidu.com/forum/w%3D580/sign=eef4736c9b3df8dca63d8f99fd1072bf/1c09d61f3a292df57ec5d18eb8315c6035a8730a.jpg

Comment: to have the entire tableview refresh you can call `[tableview reloadData]` or for the individual cell to reload you can call the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method if you know which indexPath you want to refresh.